# What is the scoring formula for Lighthouse accessibility audit?

Tags: accessibility, lighthouse

I am using Lighthouse to perform some assessment of an Angular/Node/ionic mobile app.  I am achieving 81% - 94% scores.  However, I don't know the score is computed.  I want to use the score to determine the level of effort to improve the code by the 6% - 19%.

Is it weighted?
Is it per audit with a binary pass/fail?
How many audit criteria are possible?
etc.

Answer (score 2):

The scoring is done by computing the weighted-average of the score of the list items.

Those scores can be customized within your configuration.

By default, they appear in [Lighthouse default config file](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/76cdb54e5025ad8c14f67d1ffd5ad43b3279e1a1/lighthouse-core/config/default.js) and have all the same weight. So it should be the same as the percentage of positive tests.

The score includes all tests (35 in the current version) while you might only see in the result the applicable tests.

Comment: Perfect.  One more question to expand on the answer.  Some of these tests could occur multiple times on the same page.  Is the count simply 0 or 1 regardless of how many occurrences?  Again, I am asking this with the thought of how much effort is needed to improve the page for each failure.

Comment: Customizing the score is possible. For the Accessibility section, it can't be very accurate. For example, a website can score 100, but not be keyboard accessible, because that is something that automated tests cannot check for reliably (yet). However, we are running these tests using headless-chrome and saving the reports.  We just use the score to detect if something has changed, so we know we need to go back and re-audit the website.